# Proportionally sized margin not resizing relative to screen size on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, pug

I have a section of text created via the following Jade (an HTML templating engine):

```
header
  div(class="header-logo") Order Of The Mouse: 
  div(class="header-phase") Phase 1.7 --
  div(class="header-title") Operation Silk Scarf
```

This is styled using the following CSS:

```
header {
  background-color: #78B82A;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 115px;
}

.header-logo {
  font: 1.5em Arial, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.header-phase {
  font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.header-title {
  font: 3.4em Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
}
```

(I know the CSS needs tidying up a bit, it was written in a hurry last night while quite tired).

My question is this: why does the left margin not scale for mobile devices? It seems to scale ok on my laptop in different browsers and when the window is resized, but when I access with my android device (again I've tried two different browsers) the div text is way over to the right of the screen, instead of slightly indented from the left, as I would have expected.

I can include screen-shots on mobile and non-mobile devices if necessary.

Also, it used to and should look like this:

[image: Earlier today on non-mobile: correct]

Now the code above displays as follows in a non-mobile browser (and similarly in a mobile browser):

[image: Now, non-mobile (similar on mobile): not correct]

Which is no good at all.

When the Jade is converted to HTML it currently looks like this:

```
<header><div class="header-logo">Order Of The Mouse: </div><div class="header-phase">Phase 1.7 --</div><div class="header-title">Operation Silk Scarf</div></header>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @MrLister I thought I had. What would you suggest I add or remove? I don't know what's causing the issue so it's a bit difficult to make a MCV... :/

Comment: An actual piece of HTML that we can use to try to reproduce the issue. Otherwise we'd have to come up with some HTML ourselves and you will say, "that won't help, because my HTML doesn't look like that..."

Comment: @Lister I've included the Jade file, do you want more of that? That's what I'm using in place of HTML. Would it make it easier if I convert the Jade into HTML? I can certainly do that fairly easily if you'd like me to :).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I looked over it again with fresh eyes and it looks as if this was the solution to the resizing issue:

```
header {
  background-color: #78B82A;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  height: 115px;
}

.header-logo {
  font: 1.5em Arial, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.header-phase {
  font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  left: 6px;
  top: 10px;
}

.header-title {
  font: 3.4em Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

Lord alone knows how it managed to look right last night with the code I had but somehow it did. Strange times.